# How to implement ExtractCCDAAttributes processor in Apache Nifi?

Tags: xml-parsing, apache-nifi, c-cda

I am on the process to extract some healthcare Data. Initially started with CCDA which is XML file format. How can i config the ExtractCCDAAttributes to extract the attributes  with its value?

Comment: ExtractCCDAAttributes has only one property: `Skip Validation: [ true | false ]`. there is nothing to configure... just use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this minimal flow that demonstrates use of `ExtractCCDAAttributes` processor.

[image]

1) **Get CDA Document** (Processor type: `GetFile`)

This will create a FlowFile with the document contents. The sample data file (XML) used is available [here](https://github.com/jmandel/sample_ccdas/blob/master/NIST%20Samples/CCDA_CCD_b1_Ambulatory_v2.xml).

[image]

2) **ExtractCCDAAttributes** (Processor type: `ExtractCCDAAttributes`)

This processor has a single property (`Skip Validation`) to indicate whether or not to validate CDA message values. We accept the default value of `true`. The processor outputs individual attributes as FlowFile attributes.

[image]

3) **Success** (Processor type: `LogAttribute`)

This is to log attributes upon success of `ExtractCCDAAttributes` processor.

4) **Failure** (Processor type: `LogAttribute`)

This is to log attributes upon failure of `ExtractCCDAAttributes` processor.

**Verification:**

When the [sample file](https://github.com/jmandel/sample_ccdas/blob/master/NIST%20Samples/CCDA_CCD_b1_Ambulatory_v2.xml) is processed, two of the (many) attributes logged by the **Success** processor are:

```
Key: 'vitalSignsSection.organizer_01.observations_02.code.displayName'
    Value: 'Intravascular Systolic'

Key: 'vitalSignsSection.organizer_02.observations_03.code.displayName'
    Value: 'Intravascular Systolic'
```

In the sample file, the two places where these appear are on lines 3592 and 3700:
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: I built an example like this, but it seems like only the vital signs section is being parsed.  Is the ExtractCCDA Processor incomplete or is there another reason that not all sections are being mapped to attributes?  Can you clarify here?